# CCSpriteBatchNode with large transparent backgrounds (cocos2d)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I've written a bunch of classes for creating a parallax effect background which contains the ground, hills and clouds. Each object is duplicated once and this allows me to create an infinite loop with the ground etc. Problem is, using CCSpriteBatchNode and **12 x PNG 32bit textures with approx. size 600px by 200px** slows down my FPS from 60 to 30. I have read that using CCSpriteBatchNode shows big improvements in performance, but I can't seem to replicate them.

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/09/cocos2d-spritebatch-performance-test/

How can I speed things up?

**EDIT:**
Running it on my iPhone gives me 60 FPS, but it shows 30 FPS in the simulator :S

Here's the code, if it helps, there's nothing syntactically wrong with it:

```
batch = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"parallax.png"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"parallax.plist"];
[self addChild:batch];

float screenHeight = [CCUtil screenSize].height;
float screenWidth = [CCUtil screenSize].width;

CCSprite *sky = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sky.png"];
sky.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
[batch addChild:sky];

CGPoint speedCloudSlow = ccp(0.08f, 0.002f);
CGPoint speedCloudFast = ccp(0.15f, 0.006f);

CCSprite *clouds1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"clouds1.png"];
CCSprite *clouds2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"clouds2.png"];
CCSprite *clouds3 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"clouds3.png"];
CCSprite *clouds4 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"clouds4.png"];
[batch addChild:clouds1];
[batch addChild:clouds2];
[batch addChild:clouds3];
[batch addChild:clouds4];

CCSprite *land1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"land.png"];
CCSprite *land2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"land.png"];
CCSprite *landBrown1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"land_brown.png"];
CCSprite *landBrown2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"land_brown.png"];
CCSprite *landDark1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"land_dark.png"];
CCSprite *landDark2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"land_dark.png"];
CCSprite *ground1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"ground.png"];
CCSprite *ground2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"ground.png"];

[batch addChild:land1];
[batch addChild:land2];
[batch addChild:landBrown1];
[batch addChild:landBrown2];
[batch addChild:landDark1];
[batch addChild:landDark2];
[batch addChild:ground1];
[batch addChild:ground2];
```

Comment: Did you try using CCParallaxNode before creating your own class? I was thinking about using it and I'm wondering if you had some problems with it.

Comment: It wasn't a very elegant solution to keep reducing the x or y coordinate of CCParallaxNode, but mainly I wanted to give it a shot and also add my own utility methods for adding parallax sprites that would automatically move left/right etc after they moved off screen. I'll post the class if you'd like to take a look.

Comment: As promised, my CCParallaxScrollNode class: http://ak.net84.net/iphone/creating-a-repeating-backgroundinfinite-parallax-effect-in-cocos2d/ I don't use it in this question to keep things simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Running it on my iPhone gives me 60 FPS

Perfect, so you don't actually have a problem!

FYI, whatever framerate you see in the Simulator, you should not concern yourself with that. There's no point wasting time to even think about Simulator performance. It is irrelevant, can not be compared, and bears no meaning to your application's real world performance.